# How to deal with hierarchical data with Reflux stores?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

## Outline

In my app I'm using [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) and [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) and have a hierarchical setup with regards to my data. I'm trying to break elements of my app into separate stores to be able to hook events correctly and separate concerns.

I have the following data flow:

`Workspaces -> Placeholders -> Elements`

In this scenario, when a workspace is created a default placeholder must in turn be created with a reference (ID) to the newly created workspace. The same applies for the placeholder to element relationship.

## Sticking point

The Reflux way seems to suggest the PlaceholderStore listens to the triggers from WorkspaceStore, adding the newly created ID to `this.trigger()`.

Reflux only allows a single event to be triggered from stores; thus preventing external components being able to discern `create` or `update` actions. This means that if one trigger in the store sends an ID as `argument[0]`, subsequent triggers should do the same (to remain consistent). This is a problem for components looking for updates to multiple workspaces (e.g. re-ordering / mass updates).

## Undesirable solution

I had thought to add in a concept of `StoreActions`; Actions that only stores can create, that other stores would then listen to (effectively discarding the original trigger from stores). With this components / stores could listen to specific events, and the arguments passed to said events could be tailored without worry. This seems like a wrong way to go and an abuse of the Reflux event system.

## Help

Should I be trying to break up related data? Is there a better way to structure the data instead?

I've read about aggregate stores, but not seen any implementations to dissect. Do these offer a solution by way of bringing data from multiple stores together, and if so, what is responsible for creating events React components can listen to?

Many thanks for any help / insight anyone can offer!

Comment: *I'm new to Reflux*. I find creating multiple ```store```s to be bad. I'd prefer a single action for multiple ```store```s (let's say *CRUD*), then I would pass down the store ```fn```s (```onTodoItemCreate```)for one module (let's say the ```create``` part for user), then have one main file for that module (for all the components or its ```route handler``` or template) passing the ```store handlers``` (or ```triggers```) down to components to whatever littler sub-components would need it.

Comment: New to Reflux too.

It will be easier to maintain a single store that manages appropriately complex models within. This is how I do it presently in my React/Reflux app. However, the data size grows, I may need to split the data and stores up as you are attempting to do. My point being that you may wish to start with a simpler structure, and improve it only as needed (by actual usage that demands it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Yes, it is perfectly reasonable to call actions from a store](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/158#issuecomment-67444098). I see actions as *initiators* of data flows and I consider exceptional flows as seperate ones.

A good example is a CRUD store that also handles AJAX calls (to CRUD the data with server-side). The store will trigger the change event as soon as it's data gets updated. However in the event that an AJAX call fails, it should instead start a data flow for that instead so that other stores and components can listen in on those. From the top of my head such errors are in the interest of a toast/notification component and Analytics error logging such as [GA Exceptions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/exceptions).

The AJAX example may also be implemented through the `preEmit` hook in the actions and there are [several examples among the github issues discussion](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/57) on that. There is even this ["async actions" helper](https://gist.github.com/simenbrekken/de69d3ce27ea5934c8b2).

It's by design that the stores only emit a change event. If you want to emit other kinds of events, it basically means you're starting new data flows for which you should be using actions instead.

Comment: Ahh fantastic. So I was worried over nothing. Thanks.